# Merge object keys into class

Tags: typescript

So, I have an external object whose properties get assigned to the class. How would I make typescript understand that those keys would become class' keys?

```
const object = {
  objectKey: 'whatever'
}

class someClass {
  classKey: string

  constructor(){
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => this[key] = key)
  }

  someMethod(){
    console.log(this.objectKey) // how do I make it understand it exists?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you want the compiler to know that a class's instance interface has more properties, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction).  Here's how I might do it:

```
type MyObject = typeof object; // make a named type with statically known keys
interface SomeClass extends MyObject { } // declare the SomeClass interface as extending it
class SomeClass { ... } // merge the SomeClass class instance interface into it
```

Then the compiler will see the keys/values of `object` as belonging to `SomeClass` instances too.  Note that this circumvents the [`--strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) protection and will not warn you if you fail to initialize the merged-in properties.  So be careful to do it right.  Maybe like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    classKey: string = "initializeMePlease" // compiler will catch if you don't do this

    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, object); // compiler will not catch if you don't do this
    }

    someMethod() {
        console.log(this.objectKey); // no error here now
    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsWBeGBvAUDfcSqUA0sgJ4BcMA5AO4AWAhlMgG7IBONOAvjjijkADshgBZcgHkiaGJiGiQAM0Io0AbhwBLMK07KmwMQGUQAW2QBhADZMIEGMgAerMABNHkmethYY-DjAdg4wZpa29o64BDDBUWRUMNCcugDm8jAARLraUNpMNtoAXsjiyAAKNsj2yFl4eASgkFCcAK5oIJwAFACU2I2x+D7EAHRR2mlg3VAM2hAANGrEvVqxgbEQFmXIsyDufQNDTeBb1aM2IGkzcxCjCL6JvYMBfEA)